# Trouble aligning text

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I'm having trouble aligning some text for math definitions that I am writing in LaTeX.

Here's what I currently have:

```
\newcounter{defctr}
\newenvironment{defn}
{\noindent
  \refstepcounter{defctr}
  \textbf{Definition \thesubsection.\thedefctr:}
}{\par\noindent%
  \ignorespacesafterend}
\counterwithin*{defctr}{subsection}
```

In some cases, this works fine. However, there are a few instances in which it does not work in the way I want it to. Here is an example of the command not working properly:

[image: defn not aligned]

The "definition" is not aligned with the rest of the text.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What happens if you affix `%` (the comment character) immediately after `\refstepcounter{defctr}`?

Comment: @Mico That solves my problem! Thank you so much! What does the % do?

Comment: See [What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453)

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

\newcounter{defctr}

\newenvironment{defn}`%`

{\noindent`%`

\refstepcounter{defctr}`%`

\textbf{Definition \thesubsection.\thedefctr:}`%`

}{\par\noindent%

\ignorespacesafterend}%

Comment: give % at end of line

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your answer.